# Spring Data Rest modify Repository method URI

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-rest

This may be a bit of a rudimentary question, but I have a repository where I can do a find by username as follows:

....../items/search/byUsername/?username=myusername

However, this is generally inconsistent with how AngularJS Resources treat queries. Is there a way to instead make the request URI for the same thing to be

....../items/?username=myusername

Or does that functionality not exist with spring data rest? custom methods can be made in the angular resource but it is tedious to do that for every possible search category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Angular (read: a client library) defines what URI's have to look like, then it's fundamentally violating a core REST principle — which is that clients follow links and URI templates.

That said, if you're using Querydsl and let your repository extend `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`, collection resources can be filtered by using property expressions. See the reference documentation for details.

Another option would be to manually expose resources under the URIs expected and manually forward the calls. But again, I'd argue you're better off teaching Angular to behave like a proper REST client in the first place .

Comment: Thanks Oliver. I think I was hoping to not have to deal with customizations on either side, but I think you're right customizing the angular does make more sense.